# covert dates on multiple string columns - PySpark / Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm very very new to Databricks, Spark/PySpark/Python.

I'm evaluating Databricks as part of a project to see it can maniuplate data the way other database tools can. So far i'm so so SO impressed, dataframes and Pandas dataframes are so fast and efficient.

I have a dataset with around 200 variables, 20 of which are dates in a string format yyyyMMdd, i would like to convert them all to actual dates.

I have been able to look through Stack and find a viable candidate which has worked on one variable

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime

df2 = df.withColumn('UCMOVEIN_D', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('UCMOVEIN_D', 'yyyyMMdd')).alias('date')) 
display(df2)
```

***BUT*** as i mentioned i have around 20+ variables with dates, at this point in time i dont mind repeating code, i know its not efficient but i need a fix - its my understanding there might even be a UDF which could be called with a list as an input parameter, but in my early stages, i dont know where to start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what about looping over the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the conversion in a for loop:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime, unix_timestamp

col_list = ['col1', 'col2']    # add more columns as needed

for c in col_list:
    df = df.withColumn(c, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(c, 'yyyyMMdd')))
```

Comment: this is perfect, again, very efficient - i can learn a lot from this, how would i remove the time from the end, is this a standard format of the unixtimestamp?

Comment: if you want a date you can use `to_date(c, 'yyyyMMdd')` (don't forget to import)